# Does it look like an expansion of $\log$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion

For a real number $\lambda>0$ and a positive integer $N$, consider
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-\lambda)^{\ell}}{\ell}\cdot\frac{N!}{(N+\ell)!}.
$$
Could we simplify it further as a function of $\lambda$? For example, it equals to
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{N!}{(N+\ell)!}\int_{0}^{-\lambda}v^{\ell-1}dv=N!\int_{0}^{-\lambda}\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{v^{\ell-1}}{(N+\ell)!}dv.
$$
Please give me some help or hints. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sure you recognize this when $N=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I do not recognize $\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-\lambda)^{\ell}}{\ell(\ell+1)!}$.  Could you please give me more hints?

Comment: You can write the denominator as $\ell!$ and the numerator as $(-1)^\ell\lambda^\ell$  Does that ring a bell now?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{\ell}\lambda^{\ell}}{\ell(\ell+1)\ell!}$? I still cannot figure it out.

Comment: I know that $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$. But....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we may write

\begin{align*}
F_N(\lambda) := \sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty} \frac{N!}{(N+\ell)!} \frac{(-\lambda)^{\ell}}{\ell}
&= \int_{0}^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{N! k!}{(N+1+k)!} \frac{v^k}{k!} \, \mathrm{d}v \\
&= \int_{0}^{-\lambda} \int_{0}^{1} (1 - t)^N e^{vt} \, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}v \\
&= - \int_{0}^{1} (1 - t)^N \frac{1 - e^{-\lambda t}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

This allows us to reduce each $F_N(\lambda)$ to an elementary expression plus some special functions, such as an exponential integral or incomplete gamma function.

If your primary goal is to study the asymptotic behavior of this function, then the integral representation might be more useful. For instance, we can show that $F_N(\lambda) \sim -\log \lambda$ as $\lambda \to \infty$ for each fixed $N$.

---

**Addendum.** If $\lambda = N/a$ for some $a > 0$, then as $N\to\infty$

\begin{align*}
F_N(N/a)
&= - \int_{0}^{1} (1 - t)^N \frac{1 - e^{-(N/a)t}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= - \int_{0}^{N/a} \left( 1 - \frac{au}{N} \right)^N \frac{1 - e^{-u}}{u} \, \mathrm{d}u \tag{$t = au/N$} \\
\xrightarrow[\text{as } N\to\infty]{\text{DCT}}&\quad - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-au} \left( \frac{1 - e^{-u}}{u} \right) \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \log \left( \frac{a}{a+1} \right),
\end{align*}

where the last line follows from the [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral).

Comment: Is it possible to go further if $\lambda=N/a$ for some known positive real number $a$?

Comment: @Tony, In such case, we can compute the limit of $F_N(N/a)$ as $N\to\infty$. I updated my asnwer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned a lot from you.

Comment: What if $\lambda=(N\delta)/a$ with $\delta\to0$? The asymptotic will be $-\frac{N\delta}{a(N+1)}$, am I right?

Comment: @Tony, I guess so, provided $N$ and $a$ are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$$F_N=\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-\lambda)^{\ell}}{\ell}\cdot\frac{N!}{(N+\ell)!}$$ has the typical shape of a generalized hypergeometric function.

In fact, it is
$$F_N=-\frac{\lambda }{N+1}\,\, _2F_2(1,1;2,N+2;-\lambda )$$ Even for small values of $N$, the results are not the most pleasant
$$F_0= -\log (\lambda )-\Gamma (0,\lambda )-\gamma$$
$$F_1=\frac{(1-\gamma)  \lambda +e^{-\lambda }-\lambda  (\log (\lambda )-\Gamma
   (0,\lambda ))-1}{\lambda }$$

Comment: Thanks very much